# return nested elements of array as json in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

i have an array like below :

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:1 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "type" => "validation"
      "message" => "this item not valid"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "type" => "duplicate"
      "message" => "This item is duplicate"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    2 => array:2 [
      "type" => "duplicate"
      "message" => "This item is duplicate"
    ]
  ]
]
```

i want to skip the array index and just return the nested items of array like below :

```
{
"1": {
"type": "validation",
"message: "this item not valid"
},
"1": {
"type": "duplicate",
"message: "this item not valid"
},
"2": {
"type": "validation",
"message: "this item not valid"
},
}
```

i want its type to be array so i can return it in laravel `ValidationException::withMessages`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is issue in you formatting if you will format your php array like this

```
 [
  [
   0 => [
    "type" => "validation",
    "message" => "this item not valid"
    ]
  ],
  [
   1 => [
    "type" => "duplicate",
    "message" => "This item is duplicate"
    ]
   ],
   [
    2 =>  [
    "type" => "duplicate",
    "message" => "This item is duplicate"
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Then your json result will be

```
[
 {
  "0":
    {
    "type": "validation",
    "message": "this item not valid"
    }
 },
{
 "1":
  {
    "type": "duplicate",
    "message": "This item is duplicate"
  }
},
{
"2":
  {
    "type": "duplicate",
    "message": "This item is duplicate"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it might help you. $a is your unformatted array.

```
$a = array_values($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    $a[$i] = array_values($a[$i])[0];
}
return $a;
```